# Two rows above and below specific ID based on football team points

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a db table with all the teams in the league. On the home page of the site I need to show the team`s position and two teams that have a better points (more points) and two teams bellow that have less points than the specific team. The easy part is that this specific team ID is always the same (I only need to show the current position of that one team).

```
id | Name | Points
---|------|------
0  | Team1| 9
1  | Team2| 5
2  | Team3| 3
3  | Team4| 3
4  | Team5| 2
5  | Team6| 1
```

So lets say that I want that for team3 (ID 3), the result I am looking for is

```
1. team1 9
2. team2 5
3. team3 3
4. team4 3
5. team5 2
```

I am not very good with mysql queries, please help, I am stuck.

Comment: why you have an `id` as 0 value? make `id` field as a `Primary Key`

Comment: Thank you. id is called TID in the real db and TID is the primary key and it's AI. But I did not think I needed to graphically show that in my question.

Comment: I think @SuhelMeman's point is that you say "team3 (ID 3)" when that is not true: Team3 is ID2... your numbering system has already messed you up :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers do some kind of looping construct; I prefer to handle the whole thing in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM teams
  WHERE POINTS >= (SELECT POINTS FROM teams WHERE ID=3)
  ORDER BY POINTS ASC LIMIT 0,3)
  UNION
  (SELECT * FROM teams
  WHERE POINTS < (SELECT POINTS FROM teams WHERE ID=3)
  ORDER BY POINTS DESC LIMIT 0,2)
) AS `teamResults` ORDER BY POINTS DESC
```

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a17ad/10

Here's the breakdown of what it does:

Get the team in question along with the 2 teams ahead of it.

Union that with:

Get the 2 teams directly behind our chosen team.

Finally:

Order the whole result by points, descending.

Comment: Depending on how you want... i prefer to not use >= because i do not want a row after what i put as a search.

Comment: No you need >= because what if there is a tie?  I don't follow what you're saying >= means "greater than or equal to"... check the sqlfiddle it works.

Comment: Maybe an AND WHERE id != 3 ? to exclude the team with the id we are seeing

Comment: @Goikiu look at the question and requested data. The chosen team is to be included.

Answer (score 1):

Make a query with order by points.
Then before you show start a var with value = 1;
Each loop add 1 to that var.

**Edit:**

```
SELECT * FROM teams
WHERE POINTS >= ((SELECT points FROM teams WHERE ID=3)-2)
ORDER BY points ASC LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: I don't think you understood what he was asking for; not all the teams, just 2 ahead and 2 behind.

Comment: Edited a little,you were right.

Comment: that's just going to give you 3 teams starting with the team who has 2 less points than chosenteam. See my answer.

Comment: You're is more correct, however i think that you need to toggle the >= and use only the > this way you can have both or one of the query with no result and no strange value (unwanted)

Answer (score 0):

Select all from your table and order the results by points.

Then make an array with all your team names.

When you echo the teams do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count(teams_array); $i++) {
   if (teams_array[$i]=='your_selected_team_name') {
       echo teams_array[(i+2)];
       echo teams_array[(i+1)];
       echo teams_array[i];
       echo teams_array[(i-1)];
       echo teams_array[(i-2)];
    }
}
```